# Updating variables for in-class functions after receiving user feedback

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to update the variable 'operation' from ' ' to the option the user selects. However, until it loops through, the first question always uses a random operation.

I've tried to revise my code as much as possible, and isolate the crucial code. Because of this, you'll probably need to start the programme more than once to notice that it always starts with a different option despite your selection of another.

```
import tkinter as ttk1
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

root = Tk()

def change_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
f2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

option = ""
def select_question(value):
    global option
    option = value

second_frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="How to Play")
second_frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

third_frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="Difficulty")
third_frame1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

radio1 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="plus", value="Addition", command=lambda:select_question("+"))
radio1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=18)

radio2 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="minus", value="Subtraction", command=lambda:select_question("-"))
radio2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=18)

radio3 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="times", value="Multiplication", command=lambda:select_question("*"))
radio3.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=18)

fourth_frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="Challenge")
fourth_frame1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

button = ttk.Button(fourth_frame1, text="Start", command=lambda:change_frame(f2))
button.grid(row=3, column=2)

top_frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(f2, text="Question", height=100, width=200)
top_frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=2, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

class Question:
    def __init__(self, root1):
        self.root1 = root1
        self.question_entry()
        self.generate_question()

    def question_entry(self):
        self.question = ttk1.Label(top_frame2, text="")
        self.question.grid(pady=20)  

    def generate_question(self):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        num2 = random.randint(1, 20)
        operation = option

        if operation == "":
            operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
            operation = random.choice(operators)
        if operation == "+":
            self.correct_answer = num1 + num2
        elif operation == "-":
            self.correct_answer = num1 - num2
        elif operation == "*":
            self.correct_answer = num1 * num2
        else:
            num1, num2 = num1 * num2, num1
            self.correct_answer = num1 // num2        
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} {operation} {num2}?")   

app = Question(root)
change_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call `self.generate_question()` only once inside `Question.__init__()`, so selecting *difficulty* later will not generate the question again.

Simply call `app.generate_question()` at the end of `select_question()` function to generate new question based on selection.